# Reading and Writing object through Serializable gives IO Exception on opening the file in java

Tags: java

I've to write the object of a class to .ser file. I've written the code exactly the same as it should be, but still getting the exception that says "IO Exception  while opening file". I don't know where am i going wrong. Kindly help

Here is what I've done:
Function of GUI class that is handling filing

```
    private class  ButtonClickHolder implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() == bt) {
            Student s = new Student(t1.getText(), Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()), t4.getText(), Double.parseDouble(t3.getText()), t5.getText(), t6.getText(), new Department(t7.getText(), t7.getText()));
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                // Read old objects
            ArrayList<StudentManagementApplication> StudentList = readAllData();
        // Append new object into existing list
        StudentList.add(s);
        // Open Stream for writing
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("List.ser", true));
        // Write all objects (old and new one) into the file
        for(int i = 0 ; i < StudentList.size() ; i++) {
        outputStream.writeObject(StudentList.get(i));
        }
                outputStream.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception while opening file");
    } finally { // cleanup code which closes output stream if its object was created
        try {
            if(outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();                               
        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception while closing file");
        }
    }       
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<StudentManagementApplication> readAllData()
    {
    ArrayList<StudentManagementApplication> StudentList = new ArrayList<StudentManagementApplication>(0);
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("List.ser"));
    boolean EOF = false;
    while(!EOF) {
        try {
        // read object and type cast into CarDetails object
        StudentManagementApplication myObj = (StudentManagementApplication) inputStream.readObject();
        // add object into ArrayList
        StudentList.add(myObj);
        inputStream.close();
        }     
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //System.out.println("Class not found");
        } catch (EOFException end) {
        // EOFException is raised when file ends
        // set End Of File flag to true so that loop exits
        EOF = true;
        }
    }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    //System.out.println("Cannot find file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
    //System.out.println("IO Exception while opening stream");
    //e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { // cleanup code to close stream if it was opened
    try {
        if(inputStream != null)
        inputStream.close( );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("IO Exception while closing file");
    }
    }
    // returns ArrayList
    return StudentList;
    }        
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
protected String name;
protected int phone;
protected String gender;
public Person(){

}
public Person(String n, int p, String g){
    name=n;
    phone = p;
    gender = g;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public void display(){
    System.out.println(name+ " " +phone + " "+gender);
}
```

}

Student.java

```
public class Student extends Person implements Serializable {
private double gpa;
private String Semester;
private String section;
protected Department d;
public Student(){

}   
public Student(String n, int p, String g,double g1, String s1, String s2, Department d1){
        super(n,p,g);
    gpa=g1;
    Semester = s1;
    section= s2;
    d=d1;
}

public Department getD() {
    return d;

}

public String getSemester() {
    return Semester;
}

public String getSection() {
    return section;

}

public void setD(Department d) {
    this.d = d;
}

public void setSemester(String Semester) {
    this.Semester = Semester;
}

public void setGpa(double gpa) {
    this.gpa = gpa;
}
public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}
public double getGpa() {
    return gpa;
}
```

}

Department.java

```
public class Department {
protected String name;
protected String loc;
public Department(){

}
public Department(String n, String l){
    name=n;
    loc=l;
}

public String getLoc() {
    return loc;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setLoc(String loc) {
    this.loc = loc;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void diplay(){
    System.out.println(name+ " "+loc);
}
```

}

I'm taking input from java form fields to write in file.

Comment: Perhaps if you print the actual exception, it might tell you **why** it is failing!!!

Comment: Please indent your code properly, and print and post the stack trace of the exception. Also, respect the Java naming conventions, and serialize the whole list rather than looping and serializing each element. My guess is that it's caused by the fact that only 1 of the 3 classes that you serialize implement Serializable.

Comment: @JBNizet I did as you said. I made other 2 classes implement Serializable also.

Comment: Now it is not showing any exception.

Comment: Thankyou @JBNizet.  It is working now, you saved my day.. :)